# How can I hook into Eclipse editor events in my own plugin?

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I don't want to create my own editor but I would like to extend existing editors by hooking into their editing events.

For example whenever the text changes in a text or xml editor I would get a callback and be able to react to the change.

Does such a suitable extension point exist?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this by accessing the `IEditorPart`, use `getAdapter(IDocument.class)` and then add a listener to this...

But this is really a hack... ;-)

*EDIT*: On request, here is a little more code.

```
public void hookToEditor() {
    IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
    if (page == null) return;
    IEditorPart editor = page.getActiveEditor();
    if (editor == null) return;
    IDocument doc = (IDocument) editor.getAdapter(IDocument.class);
    if (doc == null) return;

    doc.addDocumentListener(new IDocumentListener() {
        @Override
        public void documentChanged(DocumentEvent event) {
            // Do something
        }

        @Override
        public void documentAboutToBeChanged(DocumentEvent event) {
            // About to do something
        }
    });
}
```

Note that

- there are many ways to get the page - e.g. via the current site
- there are just as many ways to get the editor part - e.g. via a handler
- many editors don't have a embedded document - e.g. PDE editors

Comment: A hack will do if there is nothing else ;)

Comment: @TonnyMadsen can you give a more concrete example?

Answer (score 2):

You can add resource change listener.

```
IResourceChangeListener listener =  new IResourceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void resourceChanged(IResourceChangeEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("Text changed");
    }   
};
ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().addResourceChangeListener(listener);
```