# Listen on Eclipse Editor Events

Tags: eclipse, events, eclipse-plugin

I'm writing a plugin for Eclipse and I'm wondering how I can listen on editor text changed events for any of the active editors.

Basically I want listener events to fire when any text is modified in any of the open editors.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6508559/796559

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I hook into Eclipse editor events in my own plugin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507937/how-can-i-hook-into-eclipse-editor-events-in-my-own-plugin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to get to the JFace `Document` object associated with the editor and add an `IDocumentListener`, that should get you started.

Comment: Are there any listeners to know when a new editor is opened (ie. a new file is opened)?

Comment: Yes, `IPartListener`. This will also let you know when the parts are activated. You can see if the part is an editor because it's a subclass of `EditorPart` (or might implement some interface).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds really untypical. Also very intrusive and dangerous. Why would you want to listen to any typing in any of the editors? It is strongly recommended not to do it. Shouldn't that be limited to a bunch of editors for a same model (IEditorInput)?

```
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
            .getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
    IEditorReference[] editorReferences = page.getEditorReferences();
```

From editorReferences try and find out a way to add a listener. IEditorReference is a handle, it doesn't mean the editor is activated. When you open eclipse, editors are activated lazily (when they are clicked for opening). So activating all open editors can also cause performance issues.